# Letting User change selected OptionButton only under Condition (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In Excel I have a UserForm with two OptionButtons. If the user klicks on Option1 a condition should be checked and in case it is fulfilled Option1 should be selected, Option2 should be deselected and the function CommandButton2_Click should be executed.

If user clicks on Option2 it should be vice versa.

If the condition isn't fulfilled nothing should happen in all cases. The Condition is dependend on a yes/no-user input.

I fail to achieve this behaviour. Currently I use the "OptionButton2_BeforeUpdate"-Method. I hoped to check by this the condition first and in case it is met then change the OptionButtons Selection. However it seems, that the selection state is changed first before the BeforeUpdate-Method gets startet.

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As     MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
    CommandButton2_Click
Else
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
    CommandButton2_Click
Else
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: These are individual option buttons?  If you create a frame and place the option buttons in there only one can be selected - button 1 will automatically deselect when you click button 2 (no code for that needed).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Should just need if statement to dictate if the checkbox is checked or not based on your condition(s):

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click() 'note that this is in the click, you don't need beforeupdate 
    If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
    Else
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**  Included your actual msgbox if statement.

---

**Edit:**

Why not use something like:

```
Public mark As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    mark = MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?")
End Sub
```

Then you use "mark" for your option buttons, and as such you would have a case for either yes/no, within the option button clicks:

```
Select Case mark
    Case vbYes
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
        Me.OptionButton2.Value = False
    Case vbNo
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
        Me.OptionButton2.Value = True
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work except for the Case: Klick on 1 -> Klick No in MsgBox (Condition not Met) -> 1 and 2 are unchecked because of Me.OptionButton1.Value=False. I'd rather have 2 still checked in this scenario. If I use Me.OptionButton2.Value=True I end up in an indefinite loop of MsgBoxes.

Comment: @MatthiasLa for the sake of asking, why are you not making the yes/no upon initialize, so you can use the answer for other items?  will update with an idea

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure what the rest of your code is, but I would just set the value of the button as I wish?

Hope this helps, or at least give you an idea for next step.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
        CommandButton2_Click
        Me.OptionButton2.Value = False
    Else
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
        CommandButton2_Click
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
    Else
        Me.OptionButton2.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Sadly the OptionButton1.Value=False doesn't seem to have an effect.
So I click on OptionButton1 while 2 is selected. Then comes the popup-box with the condition. I click 'No', so the condition isn't fullfilled but still the selection changes from 2 to 1.

Comment: @MatthiasLa  Should be Me.OptionButton1.value=False

Comment: Thank you, now the OptionButton I click on gets deselected. However the one which was originally selected should remain selected but instead now nothing is selected anymore. By doing the opposite Klick on 2 -> OptionButton2.Value=True I end in an endless loop of message boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. It isn't nice but it does what I want.

```
Public Mark As Integer

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    If Mark = 1 Then
        Mark = 0
    Else
        If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
            CommandButton2_Click
            OptionButton1.Value = True
        Else
            Mark = 1
            OptionButton2.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    If Mark = 1 Then
        Mark = 0
    Else
        If MsgBox("Achtung, durch Wechsel der Getriebeart wird die Auswahl zurückgesetzt! Trotzdem wechseln?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auswahl zurücksetzen?") = vbYes Then
            CommandButton2_Click
            OptionButton2.Value = True
        Else
            Mark = 1
            OptionButton1.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite sure why you need to use the public variable (mark) for this, doesn't do anything with the above logic. You can just use the inner if/else statement, will have the same effect. Also I don't see this deselecting your option 2 by clicking option 1 and viceversa, as you`ve described... maybe i misunderstood your requirement. Anyway, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: With the public variable (mark) I check whether the order of selecting an OptionButton comes from the user or from the other Private Sub OptionButton_Click(). In the latter case I would otherwise run into a loop of MgsBoxes.